# Should the Sitemap tree in Site map Page and Sitemap.xml file must be Cross Checked for seo

Tags: php, seo, sitemap

Should the Site map page in site  and the sitemap.xml which we add along with web site file should be same?

Should the site map page depict every thing in sitemap.xml?

I want to create site map page for all the pages in my website.The website contains neary 500 pages and a PHP Smarty template system.Where can  I find SEO friendly Site map Generation script for PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should the site map page depict every thing in sitemap.xml?

No, the xml map is for the search engines and not for you website users.
In some cases, it also contains a partial pages, and links to pages to help search engine to index the site

The html map is for the users and should contain relevant links to most major categories and important pages in your site.

Site map Generation script for PHP can be found on google wiki page about sitemaps at http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators